# Proof using logical equivalences and also set builder notation. (a ∩ b) u (a ∩ b') = a

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm having a lot of trouble with this question... Specially with the second set.

Proof using logical equivalences and also set builder notation.

$$A\cup (B\cup C) = (A\cup B)\cup C$$
and
$$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B') = A$$

My answer, but I am not sure if I am correct:

Logical equivalence:
Left Hand Side, (A ∪ B) ∪ C

Let x ∈ (A ∪ B) ∪ C. If x ∈ (A ∪ B) ∪ C then x ∈ (A or B) or x ∈ C

x ∈ (A V B) V x ∈ C

x ∈ (A V B)

implies x ∈ A V x ∈ B

So, we have

=>x ∈ A V x ∈ B V x ∈ C

=>x ∈ A V x ∈ (B or C)

=>x ∈ A V (B or C)

=>x ∈ A ∪ (B ∪ C)

x ∈ (A ∪ B) ∪ C −> x ∈ A ∪ (B ∪ C)

(A ∪ B) ∪ C ⊂ A ∪ (B ∪ C)

Builder notation:
A ∪(B ∪C)= {x |x Є A U (x Є B U C)}

Second set:

(A ∩B)∪(A ∩ ¯B)=A

Logical equivalence:

LHS, (A ∩B)∪(A ∩ ¯B).

Let x ∈ (A ∩B)∪(A ∩ ¯B) −> x ∈ A

Builder notation:

(A ∩B)∪(A ∩ ¯B)={x|x Є (x Є A ∩B)x Є∪(x Є A ∩ ¯B)}

Thanks in advance

Comment: What work have you done? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Check [this site](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/setalg/setalg.html), you have the full mechanic there.